# add a password system to my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension, passwords

i have tried to implement something into my chrome extension where if the password (admin) is enterd it will execute the chrome extension (contentScript)

i have made some attempt but i am struggling at the part to execute the script on password entry is right

i am not the best at implementing html into the popup.html and at the min mine is very basic and standard , it would be great if someone could help with this section thank you

here is my manifest.json

```
{
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon16.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "js/contentScript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://www.ea.com/*fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/*" ]
   } ],
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
   "description": "A great tool that interacts with the FIFA 21 WEB APP to highlight the best deals going!",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "kappas x",
   "permissions": [ "storage", "identity", "identity.email"],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "12.9.3"
}
```

and my popup.html

```
  <body>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h1 class="logo">
        <img class="logo-icon" src="icon128.png" />Kappas
        <span class="version">(1.0.0)</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Number #1 Web App Tool For Fifa 21!</p>
      <form>
        <label for="pswd">Enter your password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="pswd">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkPswd();" />
</form>
<!--Function to check password the already set password is admin-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPswd() {
        var confirmPassword = "admin";
        var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
        if (password == confirmPassword) {
             window.location="contentScript.js";
        }
        else{
            alert("Passwords do not match.");
        }
    }
</script> 
     
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your solution to be secure, you may want to consider performing a server-side password check, meaning that when a user enters a password, you check don't check it locally, but on an external server. If you want to check for a password locally, you may do a basic `if...else` equality check, but not on the password itself, but rather on it's hashed form (Argon2 can be used for that, although I'm not sure whether you will be able to use it in a browser environment). You may also want to obfuscate your extension's code. When the user wants to change a password, its hash can be saved as a cookie or to some form of browser storage.

But as I said before - for a good security, I recommend implementing such system server-side, with user's password hashed and stored in a database.

Comment: thank u , however i dont really understand this i just want the password set in like a variable or something like that that is set